# The logic of equation solving: applying the same function on both sides. Apparent case in which the principle fails.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, soft-question, quadratics

Correct me in case I am wrong, but I think that one of the major principles of equation solving is:

> If $a = b$, then $f(a)= f(b)$, $f$ being a function.

In words "***applying the same function to  both sides of an equation yields the same output***", or maybe "applying the same function preserves equality".

Suppose that I have to solve: $$2^x = 16.$$

I apply the $\log_2$ function on both sides, which gives:

$$\log_2(2^x) = \log_2(16).$$

But $\log_2(2^x) = x$  (by definition of $\log_2$).

Hence, $x = \log_2(16)=4$.

But I come across a problem when I try to apply the aforementioned alleged principle to quadratic equations.

Suppose I have to solve: $$x^2 = 16.$$

I first apply the square root function to both sides, which yields:

$$\sqrt{x^2} = \sqrt{16}$$

and (being given that $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$)

$$| x | = 4.$$

But now I am stuck, so to say.

The reason is that I would need an "undoing absolute value function". But this "function" is not a function since it gives back $2$ outputs: $x$ OR $- x$.

Which forces me to say: $x = 4$ or $-x = 4$ (that is: $x = -4$).

Hence my question: ***is this an exception to my alleged principle, or I am wrong in assuming that the rule I stated is the major principle of equation solving?***

If I am not applying the  "$a=b \implies f(a) = f(b)$" principle, what I am doing formally in the last step of the equation solving process given above as example?

When I go from  $| x | = 4$  to  $x = 4$ OR $-x = 4$, am I applying a relation ( but no longer a function)?

Can one say "applying the same relation on both sides preserves equality?"

Comment: it's simply not one to one.

Comment: Another principle is $ab=0 \iff a=0 \lor b=0$ this can yield more solutions. $x^2=16$ is a case: $x^2 - 16=0$ iff $(x-4)(x+4)=0$ iff $x=4$ or $x=-4$ etc. Many equations will not have unique solutions, far from it. Infinitely many also occur: simple case $\sin(x)=0$ etc.

Comment: I just edited to improve your formatting. Please take a look at the changes.

Comment: @AlexKruckman-Thanks a lot for editing. I cannot get used to the keyboard machinery of the MathJax language.

Comment: You are not wrong that the rule "If $f$ is a function and $a = b$, then $f(a) = f(b)$" is *a* major principle of equation solving. But it's certainly not the *only* principle. There's no reason to expect that there's some master principle that will work to solve all possible equations!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any solution of the equation $a=b$ is also a solution of $f(a)=f(b)$. The converse need not be true.

In the simple case $2x=2$, the only solution is $x=1$. But the solutions of $4x^2=4$ are $1$ *and* $-1$.

There is no contradiction. The function we applied, namely squaring, is not one-to-one. From $a^2=b^2$ you cannot deduce $a=b$.

In the example with the logarithm, the function you apply *is* one-to-one, so it preserves equality in both directions: if $\log a=\log b$, then also $a=b$.

What about the square root? It *is* one-to-one when applied to nonnegative numbers. Indeed, you find $|x|=4$, which is solved by $x=4$ or $x=-4$, exactly as the equation $x^2=16$.

Comment: Woulld you say that the only absolutely general principle is : " the solution set of an equation of the form  f(x) = n is  the set of all x such that  the relation  nRx is true, R being the inverse relation of the function f"? In nice cases, when f is 1-1, this amounts to applying an inverse function., that " undoes" what f has done ( for example, the function " substacting 2"  that undoes what the " adding 2 " function has done to produce the equation " x+2 = 10"). But in other cases, function f has no inverse function, which means that the alledged " general principle" is not correct.

Comment: @SaintJames I wouldn't state that “general principle”: it doesn't help in any way, in my opinion.

Comment: @egreg.- Thanks for your answer.